# scala ide + playframework にて view を開くとコンパイルエラー

Tags: playframework

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

初めて質問させていただきます。
公式のドキュメントを見ながらplayframeworkの開発環境を構築したのですが、
viewを開くとどうしてもコンパイルエラーとなってしまいます。

解決策を知っている人がいましたら、
ご指導いただけると大変助かります。

Scala ide ：4.1.1
Playframework ：2.4.2

Comment: [Scala - playのviews以下のファイルでコンパイルエラー(object HtmlFormat is not a member of package play.api.templates)](http://qiita.com/shogo807/items/c99790c2eeacc4230d6b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自分の回避方法を挙げておきます。
環境はScala IDE (Build id: 4.2.0-vfinal-2015-09-25T11:10:29Z-Typesafe)

htmlソース上で -> 右クリック -> Preferences…

[image]

General -> Editors -> Structured Text Editors -> 【Appearance】の"Report problems as type" のチェックをOFF

[image]

あとは Project -> Clean… して終わり

以上

Comment: なるほど。今まではviewを開くとコンパイルエラーになってうっとおしかったのがこれなら回避できますね。
ご教授いただき感謝いたします。

Answer (score 1):

Scala IDEのバグです。
https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-ide-play2/issues/249
まだ、修正されていません。議論はissuesのリンクにあるgoogleグループを参考にしてください。

Comment: なるほど原因はバグでしたか、議論のほうを見守っていこうとおもいます。
素早い回答ありがとうございました。感謝いたします。